# How to write log files to absolute path in Databricks using logging module

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, python-logging

I am trying to write logs to a file in my Databricks notebooks using the python logging module and fileHandler while adding logs to the log file to an s3 bucket.

But when I try a path to an s3 bucket, I will get this error:

`No such file or directory: '/databricks/driver/s3:/path/to/file.log`

I am not sure how to use an absolute path with the handler vs the default OS directory. The only other solution I can think of is to have a function at the end of notebooks that add the file to the s3 bucket, but I want the logs to be appended to the s3 log file as the logs are created.

```py
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s — %(message)s")
LOG_FILE = 's3://path/to/file.log'

def get_file_handler():
   file_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
   file_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
   return file_handler

def get_logger(logger_name):
   logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   logger.addHandler(get_file_handler())

   logger.propagate = False
   return logger
```